# how to display marker on the map using GeoJSON Map

Tags: javascript

Note:
I edit my previous post so you might read some irrelevant answer to my question

Hi may I ask from help from you guys I want to display the markers according to what is inside the database
Here is my code
**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        for (i = 0; i < markerss.length; i++)
        {
            var data = markerss[i]
            console.log(data);
        }
    </script>
```

when I console.log the variable data it displays all my countries and their respective coordinates but I cannot display it by markers in the map 
**Disclaimer**
I am just a beginner and I also apologize for my poor english

Comment: Did you figured out a way to call stored procedure from C# and retrieve username from it? If yes then you can add an `<asp:Label` in the div and set its text property from the code behind.

Comment: Is "Username" your variable name in the code behind? If so do you know how to get the database value into that variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect  to your database using an ORM like EF (Enitty Framework) and display your data withing html by passing the read value from DB through controller (in  case you develop asp.net MVC )

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking to add by client side or server side?

```
- Client side

    <div id="idUser" class="row" style="color:#FFF;font-weight:bold;"></div>

    $("#idUser").text("Mark D");



- Server side

    <div id="idUser" class="row" style="color:#FFF;font-weight:bold;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>

    lblUser.Text = "Mark D";
```

Comment: via Server Side